# Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value and save

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort this array by the value of the "seasons" field first, then of the "series" field? And save the keys

```
        Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 2
                            [series] => 3
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 2
                            [series] => 1
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 2
                            [series] => 2
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 1
                            [series] => 1
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 1
                            [series] => 3
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 1
                            [series] => 2
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                )
        )
    )
```

usort, ksort functions does not save the keys, but sorting by seasons and series values really good

After usort function:

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 1
                            [series] => 1
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 1
                            [series] => 2
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 1
                            [series] => 3
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 2
                            [series] => 1
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 2
                            [series] => 2
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [season] => 2
                            [series] => 3
                            [title] => Boom
                        )

                )
        )
```

Who can help me solve this problem?

Comment: How do you get the array? From a database?

Comment: Yes, from a database

Comment: Then sort in directly in the query. For 1 sql is faster then php 2 it's a lot cleaner

Comment: thx

Solved by array_walk

Comment: post your answer so this can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Solved by array_walk

```
array_walk($arr, function($a, $b){
        return $a['season'] - $b['season'];
    });
```